# Serializing object to XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlserializer

I have a class in C# setup that serializes itself to XML, and this class has a List of objects that it serializes as well.

```
[XmlRoot("Config")]
public class ConfigSerializer {

    [XmlArray("Nodes")]
    public List<Node> LstNodes { get; set; }  

}
```

And here is the class declaration for Node.

```
[XmlRoot("N")]
public class Node {
  // has a few different properties
}
```

PROBLEM: When I serialize an instance of ConfigSerializer to XML it doesn't serialize the XML as I would expect it to with regards to the Node list. It looks like this...

```
<Config>
  <Nodes>
    <Node></Node>
  </Nodes>
</Config>
```

But I would expect it to look like this (because of the XmlRoot declaration for the Node class)...

```
<Config>
  <Nodes>
    <N></N>
  </Nodes>
</Config>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this

```
    [XmlRoot("Config")]
    public class ConfigSerializer
    {
        [XmlArray("Nodes"),XmlArrayItem("N")]
        public List<Node> LstNodes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: XmlArray Attribute is the solution for sure, +1